# Return numeric value for pandas count function

Tags: python, pandas

```
print(test.query('code == ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]') [['code']].count())
```

This does not return a numeric value that can be compared with a > operator (greater than). How can I change that?

This is why `if test.query('code == ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]') [['code']].count()>0:` will print an error message.

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem is your code return one item `Series`, because `[[code]]` - it return one column DataFrame.

```
test = pd.DataFrame({
        'code':list('ABCDEF'),
})

print(test.query('code == ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]')[['code']])
  code
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    D
4    E

print(test.query('code == ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]') [['code']].count())
code    5
dtype: int64
```

For scalar change to `['code']` for count of `Series`:

```
print (test.query('code == ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]')['code'].count())
5
```

Another idea is get lengths of DataFrame by `len`:

```
print (len(test.query('code == ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]')))
5
```

Or using [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and count `True`s by `sum`:

```
print (test['code'].isin(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]).sum())
5
```